# Why my javascript code to connect sqlite DB(physical file) is not working

Tags: javascript, sqlite

My Javascript piece of code is like this

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<script>
var db = openDatabase('test', '1.0', 'my first database', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
db.transaction(function (tx) {
tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS foo (id unique, text)');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO foo (id, text) VALUES (1, "synergies")');
});
</script>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

I came to know from http://html5doctor.com/introducing-web-sql-databases/ web sql database should work in `crome`. But this is not working .

Comment: what errors do you get?

Comment: No error is coming in crome console .

Comment: what is not working ?

Comment: So it should create a new table `foo` in sqlite db called  `test`. Which is not happening

Comment: [works for me...](http://i.imgur.com/Ugkcedg.png)

Comment: Strange , I am not sure what is the prob with mine

Comment: @DibyenduDutta did you check the resources tab and webdb

Comment: @Fast Snail I got it now , its creating a web sql database called `test` and table called `foo`. My idea was it will read my test.db SQLite  and will perform transaction on the same physical db file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108808/discussion-between-dibyendu-dutta-and-fast-snail).